# Recyclerview GridLayoutManger - how to change order of items? Displaying two lists next to each other

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

Basically I have 2 lists, 1 to 10, and I want to display them in recyclerview one next to the other, something like this:

```
1  1
2  2
3  3
.  .
.  .
10 10
```

What I have tried is GridLayoutManager with 2 columns, but what I'm getting is this:

[image]

You can see it's populating grid from left to right, but I want it to go from top to bottom and when it gets to the new list, displays it in the 2nd column.

Any advice how can i make that?

I'm using [recyclerviewMergeAdapter](https://github.com/martijnvdwoude/recycler-view-merge-adapter) because I thought it's a good approach. If there's better solution in this situation let me know.

```
private final PolazakAdapterRv adapter1;
private final PolazakAdapterRv adapter2;
private final RecyclerViewMergeAdapter mergeAdapter;

@BindView(R.id.recyclerViewWorkDays)
RecyclerView recyclerView;


public DaysFragmentView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    inflate(getContext(), R.layout.fragment_work_days, this);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    mergeAdapter = new RecyclerViewMergeAdapter();

    adapter1 = new PolazakAdapterRv(getContext());
    adapter2 = new PolazakAdapterRv(getContext());

    mergeAdapter.addAdapter(adapter1);
    mergeAdapter.addAdapter(adapter2);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(mergeAdapter);
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
}


public void setRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Integer>[] lists) {
    List<Integer> list1 = lists[0];
    List<Integer> list2 = lists[1];

    adapter1.setMap(list1);
    adapter2.setMap(list2);

    mergeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Timber.d("RecyclerView updated!");
}
```

PolazakAdapterRv:

```
public class PolazakAdapterRv extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PolazakHolder> {

private final Context context;
private List<Integer> list;

public PolazakAdapterRv(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = new ArrayList<>();
}


public void setMap(List<Integer> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public PolazakHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.rv_polazak, parent, false);
    return new PolazakHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PolazakHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.textViewPolazakHour.setText(list.get(position).toString());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}
```

Comment: Do you want them to scroll individually? Can you set up two RecyclerViews next to one another?

Comment: No, i've wanted them to scroll together, to be like same list.

Comment: Can you pass both maps into the Adapter, and have the same list item view display the data from the both of them by adding an additional TextView?

Comment: "No, i've wanted them to scroll together, to be like same list" - in this case I'd use a LinearLayoutManager with a row layout with two TextViews and my adapter would access the two data lists to fill the two TextViews for each row position ( = index of either data list). But maybe your GridLayoutManager issue can be fixed by using [setOrientation()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#setOrientation(int)) which is inherited from LinearLayoutManager. Maybe not - there's too little code for me to know for sure.

Comment: "Can you pass both maps into the Adapter, and have the same list item view display the data from the both of them by adding an additional TextView?" - I think that wouldn't work because i don't how many items i will have in any of those 2 lists.
This example is just simplified what i'm actually doing, but this is the core what i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is one adapter with two view types and a simple logic for indexing the right thing. Sample code:

```
public class PolazakAdapterRv extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PolazakHolder> {
private final Context context;
private List<Integer> list1;
private List<Integer> list2;

public PolazakAdapterRv(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public void setList1(List<Integer> list) {
    this.list1 = list;
}

public void setList2(List<Integer> list) {
    this.list2 = list;
}

@Override
public PolazakHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.rv_polazak, parent, false);
    return new PolazakHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PolazakHolder holder, int position) {
    int index = position / 2; // assumes there are two lists of equal lengths
    int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
    if (viewType == TYPE_1) {
        holder.textViewPolazakHour
        .setText(list1.get(index).toString());
    }
    else if (viewType == TYPE_2) {
        holder.textViewPolazakHour
        .setText(list2.get(index).toString());
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list1.size() + list2.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position % 2 == 0 ? VIEW_TYPE_1 : VIEW_TYPE_2;
}
```

Breaking it down:

The one adapter has the two lists you want to display so they all scroll together.

You have two view types that describe each list.

Since you want two columns to show each list separately, logically this just means you alternate what you show in each cell. So when the position is even (left column) you return VIEW_TYPE_1. When the position is even (right column) you return VIEW_TYPE_2.

The total count in the adapter is simply the total count of both lists.

The view layout is the same (I guess) so you can use the same `onCreateViewHolder`.

Finally, when binding the viewholder, you just need to know which view type you're working with based on the index and which model object to use. So just ask your `getViewType` method for the right view type to know which list to use, and simply divide the position by 2 for the right index into the list. Whether position is even or odd, int division will yield the proper index into the given list.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what i've needed.